# Auto mount attached drives with specified PARTUUID using udev?

Tags: udev, automounting, partition-table

I used to do auto-mounting with udev like this:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-aaa.rules
KERNEL=="sda1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/etc/mymount.sh"

# cat /etc/mymount.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$ACTION" = "add" ]; then
    # Do some stuff
    mount /dev/sda1
elif [ "$ACTION" = "remove" ]; then
    # Do some other stuff
    umount /mnt/usba
fi

# cat /etc/fstab | grep sda1
/dev/sda1  /mnt/usba  ext4  auto,rw,noatime,user  0  0
```

However I noticed that the letter for my drive may change, so I changed the `fstab` entry to this

```
PARTUUID=12345678-01  /mnt/usba  ext4  auto,rw,noatime,user  0  0
```

But it's no longer working because `/dev/sda*` is permantly attached (another drive) and I can't simply change the udev rule to `sdb`. How can I configure my udev rule so that it gets mounted correctly?

Comment: `udevadm info --query=all -a --name sdXy` For sdXy take the name of the devicenode.

Comment: @Bahamut What is the device node? Like `/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1` ?

Comment: No, like /dev/sdb1.

Comment: @Bahamut But that changes every time I plug the drive in.

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` plug the hd in and you can see how it is recognize. then you can use udevadm and show it.